# The app freezes when I try to open the Home screen - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On the Home screen, I added Bottom Navigation. After adding it, when I try to open the Home screen, the app freezes, it doesn't show any errors. When I remove the Bottom Navigation, the Home screen works normally. The code from the Home screen is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Dimensions, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import TicketsScreen from './tickets/tickets';
import MembershipScreen from './membership/membership';
import HelpScreen from './help/help';
import ProfileScreen from './profile/profile';

// Create a bottom tab navigator
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(false);

  const openPopup = () => {
    setPopupVisible(true);
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setPopupVisible(false);
  };

  const selectOption = (option) => {
    setSelectedOption(option);
    closePopup();
  };

  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const fontSize = screenWidth < 600 ? 16 : 24;

  const slides = [
    {
      key: '1',
      image: require('../assets/Slider/Home-Slider.jpg'),
      header: 'The Jane Hotel Ballroom 1',
      description: 'This century-old West Village landmark, built in 1908 as a sailors lodging, lies on the edge of the Meatpacking.',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      image: require('../assets/Slider/Home-Slider.jpg'),
      header: 'The Jane Hotel Ballroom 2',
      description: 'This century-old West Village landmark, built in 1908 as a sailors lodging, lies on the edge of the Meatpacking.',
    }
  ];

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.container}>

          <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <View style={styles.headerModalContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={openPopup}>
                <Text style={styles.headerModalSelectedOption}>
                  {selectedOption || 'City 1'}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.MessagesContainer}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='email' size={25} color="#ffffff" style={styles.MessagesIcon} />
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType='slide'
                visible={popupVisible}
                onRequestClose={closePopup}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.ModalView}
                  onPress={closePopup}
                >
                  <View style={styles.ModalContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.ModalTextView}>
                      Selected City: <Text style={styles.ModalSelectedOption}>{selectedOption || 'City 1'}</Text>
                    </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selectOption('City 1')}>
                      <Text style={styles.ModalOptions}>City 1</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selectOption('City 2')}>
                      <Text style={styles.ModalOptions}>City 2</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selectOption('City 2')}>
                      <Text style={styles.ModalOptions}>City 3</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Modal>


            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.SearchBoxContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#129990', padding: 10, borderRadius: 5 }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='magnify' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
                <TextInput
                  placeholder='Search events, venues, facilities'
                  style={{ marginLeft: 10, flex: 1, color: '#A0A0A0' }}
                  placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>

          <View style={styles.FeaturedFacilities}>
            <View style={styles.FeaturedFacilitiesHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.FeaturedFacilitiesText}>Featured facilities</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.SlidersContainer}>
            <Swiper showsButtons={false} showsPagination={false}>
              {slides.map((slide) => (
                <View key={slide.key} style={styles.SliderContainer}>
                  <Image source={slide.image} style={styles.SliderImage} resizeMode="cover" />
                  <View style={styles.overlay} />
                  <Text style={styles.SliderHeader}>{slide.header}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.SliderDescription}>{slide.description}</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </Swiper>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.UpcomingEventsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventsHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsText}>Upcoming Events</Text>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsSeeAll} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UpComingEvents')}>See all</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.UpomingEventsCubesContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventCubeContainer}>
              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-1.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Nightless Wednesday</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/15 at Club Solterios</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-2.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Thursday Night</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/18 at Student Club</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.JustForYouContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventsHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsText}>Just For You</Text>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsSeeAll} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UpComingEvents')}>See all</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.JustForYouCubesContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventCubeContainer}>
              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-1.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Nightless Wednesday</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/15 at Club Solterios</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-2.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Thursday Night</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/18 at Student Club</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.FacilitiesContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventsHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsText}>Facilities</Text>
              <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventsSeeAll} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UpComingEvents')}>See all</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.FacilitiesCubesContainer}>
            <View style={styles.UpcomingEventCubeContainer}>
              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-3.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Nightless Wednesday</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/15 at Club Solterios</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.UpcomingEventBox}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/UpcomingEvents/Object-4.jpg')}
                  style={styles.UpcomingEventImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={styles.UpcomingEventContent}>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventHeader}>Thursday Night</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.UpcomingEventDescription}>6/18 at Student Club</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>

        </View>

      </ScrollView>

      <View style={styles.container22}>
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#129990',
              },
              style: {
                borderTopWidth: 0, // Hide top border
              },
              tabBarShowLabel: false,
              paddingTop: 6,
              paddingBottom: 6,
            },
              labelStyle: {
            display: 'none', // Hide labels
                            },
          activeTintColor: '#fff',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#71CAC4',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
                        }}
                    >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Dashboard}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="Dashboard" color={color} size={size} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Tickets"
            component={TicketsScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="ticket" color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Membership"
            component={MembershipScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Help"
            component={HelpScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="help-circle" color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
    </View >
    );
};
```

When I remove this part of the code everything is okay.

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#129990',
      },
      style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0, // Hide top border
      },
      tabBarShowLabel: false, // Brisanje labela ispod ikonica
      tabStyle: {
        paddingTop: 6,
        paddingBottom: 6,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        display: 'none', // Hide labels
      },
      activeTintColor: '#fff',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#71CAC4',
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Dashboard}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="Dashboard" color={color} size={size} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Tickets"
      component={TicketsScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="ticket" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Membership"
      component={MembershipScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Help"
      component={HelpScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="help-circle" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Your first section of code throws errors about mismatched closing tags.  That said, you should provide a *minimal* reproducible example

Comment: It doesn't show any errors for me, just a frozen screen @possum

Comment: `Dashboard` component is calling itself inside the tab navigator to cause the freeze. Please split the tab to another functional component.

Comment: I didn't understand you well. Can you explain me or write the possible solution? @kiuQ

Answer (score 0):

A loop of React component exists in `Dashboard` component. You put the tab navigator inside the `Dashboard` and the tab navigator uses `Dashboard` also. React Native cannot handle this kind of navigator component loop, therefore the screen will freeze.

The solution is simple, delete the tab navigator in dashboard component and just take out tab navigator as another component.

**Create navigator.js**

```
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
//...Rest of the import statement

export default function Navigator() {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator
       screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#129990',
       },
       style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0, // Hide top border
       },
       tabBarShowLabel: false, // Brisanje labela ispod ikonica
       tabStyle: {
        paddingTop: 6,
        paddingBottom: 6,
       },
       labelStyle: {
        display: 'none', // Hide labels
       },
       activeTintColor: '#fff',
       tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#71CAC4',
       tabBarActiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
     }}
   >
     <Tab.Screen
       name="Home"
       component={Dashboard}  //Here is where the loop happens in question
       options={{
         tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
             <MaterialCommunityIcons name="Dashboard" color={color} size={size} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
         ),
       }}
     />
     //{...Rest of your screens}}
   </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 )
}
```

You may read the [React Navigation document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#api-definition) to see more details about tab navigators.